# i have installed devstack in VM, how i can do to reboot and don't lose all

Tags: cloud, openstack, distributed, devstack

i have just installed Devstack in VM for my University Tesis but whenever i shutdown the virtual machine i lost all.
the command ./rejoin-stack.sh do not exist in the newer version of Devstack.

How i can do?

Answer (score 2):

From the [commit message](http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-dev/devstack/commit/?id=9ba49cd82631ada84b8458b370ac535985d57725) that removed rejoin-stack,

> Requiring a complete re-run of DevStack after a reboot has always been intentional.

You should investigate a different way to run OpenStack for your thesis.